# Using Mapped Types to map an array of generic types to a different (return) array

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function which takes a variable number of input parameters and returns an array of the same length, with the items having the generic types specified when the function is called. It's actually a function which returns a `Promise` array.

Using mapped types I did this:

```
export const Service = {
   /* ... */
   promisify: <T extends [] = any>(...p: Array<string>): { [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> } => {
      const result = [];
      /* ... */
      return result;
   }
}
```

but it's giving an error because an object is declared as the return type...

What I'm trying to achieve is someting allong these lines:

```
/*pseudocode*/
export const Service = {
   promisify: <T extends [] = any>(...p: Array<string>): [ [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> ] => {
      const result = [];
      /* ... */
      return result;
   }
}
```

The result I'm after is being able to call this function and have the right return type:

```
Service.promisify<number>("val1"); //=> [Promise<number>]
Service.promisify<number, string>("val1", "val2"); //=> [Promise<number>, Promise<string>]
Service.promisify<number, string, MyType>("val1", "val2", "val3"); //=> [Promise<number>, Promise<string>, Promise<MyType>]
```

Is this currently possible using mapped types or do I need to specifiy overloads?

Comment: unclear to me what `p` is used for in the type. You return a tuple, tuples don't have members names. If you just want to pass in a tuple of simple types and return a tuple of promises that is possible, but again not sure what role you want those names to play here.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I got inspired from [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063#issuecomment-409706254). Yes, what I need is to map a tuple of types to an array of promises: `<T_1, T_2, ... T_n> --> [Promise[T_1], Promise[T_2], ..., Promise[T_n]]`. The return type of a promise should be the corresponding type in the type tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general idea should work, you just have a couple of issues around syntax. There is no mapped tuple syntax, but regular mapped types work with tuples as expected (since 3.1 I believe).

Also you need to constrain `T` to be an array type, and you will need to pass in the types you want to map as a tuple:

```
export const Service = {
   promisify: <T extends any[]>(): { [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> } => {
      const result = [] as any as { [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> };
      /* ... */
      return result;
   }
}

Service.promisify<[number]>(); //=> [Promise<number>]
Service.promisify<[number, string]>(); //=> [Promise<number>, Promise<string>]
Service.promisify<[number, string, MyType]>(); //=> [Promise<number>, Promise<string>, Promise<MyType>]
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it also be possible map to a single `Promise` with the type of the tuple: `<T_1, T_2, ... T_n> --> [Promise[T_1, T_2, ..., T_n]]`?

Comment: @AndreiV yes, but that would be a simple  `promisify: <T extends any[]>(): [Promise<T>]` no mapped types required

Comment: Eh, sorry, forgot the array there. This is what I meant (single Promise): `<T_1, T_2, ... T_n> --> Promise<[T_1, T_2, ..., T_n]>`. That's just one promise which resolves to an Array of types (the tuples).

Comment: @AndreiV since `T` is the tuple now, you can just do `Promise<T>` that will resolve to `Promise<[number, string, MyType]>` for the last call, again in this case no need for any mapped type magic. The only caveat is at call site `T` needs to be the tuple already, TS does not have the concept of variable number of type parameters

Answer (score 0):

`promisify()` returns an object. If you want to return an object, initialize it with `{}` and define its type with `as MyType`, the method return type will be inferred. I also prefer `A[]` (more Typescript way) instead of `Array<A>` (more C#/Java way):

```
  promisify: <T extends [] = any>(...p: string[]) => {
    const result = {} as { [P in keyof T]: Promise<T[P]> };
    /* ... */
    return result;
  }
```